# CV heading to include participation in scientific/organization commitees?

Tags: cv, program-committee

How do you name the section on your CV to list your participation as scientific/organization members in academic events (e.g. conferences, workshops, etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Service" activities are usually listed under a heading such as "Professional Service" or "Professional Activities." However, this does **not** apply to simply attending or presenting at conferences and workshops, but rather to organizing or scientific committees.

Comment: Thank you. Professional Service / Activities are a good name. I will use it for  organizing events

Answer (score 0):

If you've done only a few and they're very relevant to your field I would create a separate field for "Workshops."  I've done quite a few as both a participant and a lecturer and so I lump the most recent and relevant under "Panels/Workshops."